# Application of Componendo and Dividendo Rule and Dimensional Analysis

Tags: dimensional-analysis, mathematics

Let us consider the following ratio:

$$\frac A B=\frac C D$$

where $A$,$B$,$C$, and $D$ are of different dimensions. Can we apply the Componendo and Dividendo from Algebra as given below?:

$$\frac{A+B}{A-B}=\frac{C+D}{C-D}$$

*Why do I think "no"?*

Since $A$,$B$,$C$, and $D$ are of different dimensions, and we know that only quantities of same dimensions must be added or subtracted, we must not apply the Componendo and Dividendo. The equation obtained is dimensionally incorrect and hence totally invalid.

*Why do I think "yes"?*

In kinematics, I learnt the following formula to determine the displacement in the $t$ th second:

$$S_t=u+\frac a 2(2t-1)$$

Clearly the above equation is also dimensionally incorrect, but if I were more careful while deriving the above equation, I would have got the following where I've taken dimensions into account:

$$S_t=u(1s)+\frac a 2 (2t-(1s))(1s)$$

The above equation is dimensionally correct unlike the first form. I thought, in the similar manner, if we have some proper dimension corrective terms (which don't alter the magnitude) in the Componendo and Dividendo like the following:

$$\frac{d_1A+d_2B}{d_1A-d_2B}=\frac{d_3C+d_4D}{d_3C-d_4D}$$

where $d_1$,$d_2$,$d_3$ and $d_4$ are appropriate dimension correcting terms like the $(1s)$ in the kinematics equation, the above equation will become dimensionally correct. Under this circumstance, will the result obtained be correct?

In short, can we apply the Componendo and Dividendo rule by just neglecting the dimensions as we use to in kinematics? If no, kindly explain why the familiar rule from Mathematics fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof of the componendo and dividendo rules is as follows:

> If $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}$, then $\frac{A}{B}\pm1=\frac{C}{D}\pm1$. Since $1=\frac{B}{B}=\frac{D}{D}$, we have that $\frac{A}{B}\pm 1=\frac{A\pm B}{B}$ and $\frac{C}{D}\pm 1=\frac{C\pm D}{D}$. This means that $\frac{A\pm B}{B}=\frac{C\pm D}{D}$. For componendo, use $+$, and for dividendo, use $-$.
>
> Since $\frac{A+B}{B}=\frac{C+D}{D}$ and $\frac{A-B}{B}=\frac{C-D}{D}$, dividing the two, we have $\frac{\frac{A+B}{B}}{\frac{A-B}{B}}=\frac{\frac{C+D}{D}}{\frac{C-D}{D}}$, so $\frac{A+B}{A-B}=\frac{C+D}{C-D}$.

The problem with this proof when units are involved lies at the very beginning. If $\frac{A}{B}$ and $\frac{C}{D}$ are quantities with units, you can only add to them quantities with the **same units**. In other words, $1$ must have the *same units* as $\frac{A}{B}$ and $\frac{C}{D}$.

But later in the proof, we use the fact that $1=\frac{B}{B}=\frac{D}{D}$. This means that the number $1$ *must be unitless*, since the units of the $B$ in the numerator are the same as the units of the $B$ in the denominator.

These two statements:

- The units of $1$ must match the units of $\frac{A}{B}$
- $1$ must be unitless

are **contradictory** unless $\frac{A}{B}$ and $\frac{C}{D}$ are also unitless. This means that $A$ and $B$ must have the same units, and $C$ and $D$ must have the same units.

So, the rule in question is only applicable if $A$ and $B$ have the same units, and $C$ and $D$ have the same units. Note that the units of $A$ and $B$ are **not** required to be the same as the units of $C$ and $D$.

Answer (score 1):

If you add two things, their units must match. While typing this bit out, [probably_someone provided an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/517475/6634) on where the componendo/dividendo rule comes from. Hopefully that ties in well here to show you that any time units are involved, you need to carefully track them through the entire process.

Let's take your example of the displacement over the $t$-th second and figure out what happened to the units. There are two ways of deriving this, both starting from the equation for position as a function of time:

$$ S = u t + \frac{1}{2}a t^2$$

The algebraic way is to find the position at $t = t_1$ and the position at $t = t_1 + 1$ where 1 has units of seconds because it is time. If you plug those in and subtract them, you get:

$$S_t = u (1 s) + \frac{1}{2}a \left( 2t_1 (1 s) + (1 s) \right)$$

which is what you stated in your question. But it's really important to think about what this means -- those units of seconds didn't pop up randomly, they came about because you inserted 1 second into your equation for the later position.

What if we made it a variable instead? That would mean we plug in for $t = t_1$ and $t = t_1 + \Delta t$ where $\Delta t$ also has units of seconds, but can take any value of interest. Now we find both $S$ values and subtract and get:

$$ S_t = u\Delta t + \frac{1}{2} a \left(2 t_1 \Delta t + \Delta t^2\right)$$

And now we can again see that the units make sense and everything is complete. Since $\Delta t$ can be anything, we can plug in $\Delta t = 1 s$ and get the answer you had before. We can also plug in $\Delta t = 100 s$ and it works, or $\Delta t = 0.0001 s$ and it works. In other words, the equation with $\Delta t$ gives you the displacement over $\Delta t$ seconds starting at $t = t_1$.

---

Now we can get into something more advanced. When we plug in $\Delta t = 1 s$, we are finding the total displacement over 1 s, rather than finding the instantaneous displacement at $t = t_1$. So if we divide both sides by $\Delta t$, we can get the displacement per $\Delta t$:

$$ \frac{S_t}{\Delta t} = u + \frac{1}{2}a(2t_1 + \Delta t) $$

This is a handy formula, but we still have to pick a value of $\Delta t$. What if I want to know the displacement over an incredibly tiny $\Delta t$? So tiny that I'm interested in the smallest possible $\Delta t$ that is greater than zero? We can write:

$$ \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{S_t}{\Delta t} = u + \frac{1}{2}a\left(2t_1 + \text{very very small number}\right) = u + at_1$$

which is true for any $t = t_1$ and so we can just write it as $u + at$. We're still dimensionally consistent, but we've now found the equation for the displacement at time $t$ over the next incredibly tiny $\Delta t$. This definition of displacement over tiny time changes is the *velocity* at the instant $t$ and it is the *derivative* of the displacement function.